# Running IAsyncOperation from a Windows Runtime Component using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading, win-universal-app

I have a solution that has both a Windows Runtime Component (C#) and a Universal App (JS).

One of my classes in the WRC has the following static function:

```
public static IAsyncOperation<Project> Import()
{
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run<Project>(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");
            StorageFile source = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (source != null)
            {
                StorageFile destination = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFileAsync(source.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await source.MoveAndReplaceAsync(destination);
                return await Project.Open(source.DisplayName);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }).AsAsyncOperation<Project>();
}
```

I am trying to call this function from JS using:

```
SignalOne.Data.Project.import().done(function () {
    new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageBox("Done").showAsync();
}
```

However, while the "Done" message appears, the file open dialog does not. If I put a message box as the first line inside the try of the C#, it doesn't display, either.

I know I have an upper-case Import in C# and a lower-case import in JS, but that is how it comes up with Intellisense, and if I change it to upper-case in JS it crashes.

I'm sure I'm missing something small/stupid, but I can't put my finger on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you known, if we want to use the async method in Windows Runtime Components, we should be able to use the [WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsAsyncAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.asasyncaction.aspx) or [AsAsyncOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh779745.aspx) extension method to wrap the task in the appropriate interface.

> You can use .NET Framework tasks (the Task class and generic Task class) to implement your asynchronous method. You must return a task that represents an ongoing operation, such as a task that is returned from an asynchronous method written in C# or Visual Basic, or a task that is returned from the Task.Run method.

For more info, see [Asynchronous operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic#asynchronous-operations).

Also the FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync method should be run in UI thread.

> In this example, the event is being fired on the UI thread. If you fire the event from a background thread, for example in an async call, you will need to do some extra work in order for JavaScript to handle the event. For more information, see Raising Events in Windows Runtime Components.

So we should be able to use `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread` method get the UI thread before the async Task is run that the async Task is not run on the UI thread.

For example:

```
var window = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
var m_dispatcher = window.Dispatcher;
```

Then we should be able to use the [`FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.picksinglefileasync.aspx) method in the [`CoreDispatcher.RunAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx) method.

For example:

```
 await m_dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(async () =>
{
    var source = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
}));
```

Comment: Hi Jayden, thanks for your reply. When I change to:

    StorageFile source = null;
    await Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler(async delegate() {
        source = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    }));

I get an invalid window handle exception.